# Firebase - Allow user access to parts of database based on database information

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I know how you can give a user read/write access to parts of the database using his UID, but I want to do something that is a little but more complicated, and I don't know how to do it. If I have a database structure like this:

- Users:

  - oixMNpuyaaTTntNVl17MC74wL8e2:

    - accesTo:

      - Some Name: 'some value'
      - Some Other Name: 'some other value'
- Stuff

  - Some Name

    - Information: 'More information'
    - InformationMore: 'Some more information'

In this case, I need user `oixMNpuyaaTTntNVl17MC74wL8e2` to be able to access all the data under `Some Name`, which was specified somewhere else in the database. I hope I was able to explain my issue properly, and that this is possible! Also, it is not okay to set the `Some Name` child of `Stuff` to `oixMNpuyaaTTntNVl17MC74wL8e2`, because other users might also have access to `Some Name`.

Note: I'm using Firebase Web and Admin as well, using Python (Flask) and JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your problem, if this isn't what you're looking for, please edit your question and explain what you're looking for in more depth.

If you want to limit access to "Some Name" to only users who have that access granted under the "Users" table, then you can write a rule that looks for the "Some Name" permission under that user. This rule would apply to all users of your app, so any user that has the access granted will be able to access that data.

Your rule would look like:

```
{
  "rules": {

    "Stuff": {
      "$someName": {
        ".read": "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('accesTo').val() == $someName"
      }
    },

    // ...etc... other rules for other tables in your database

}
```

There are plenty more examples of this kind of thing [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data).

Comment: That looks spot on. Great answer Jeremy!

Comment: I'm really sorry - I made a small mistake in my database structure - the user actually has multiple things which he can access, and they're all key names, and I so I need to check if any one keyname matches. How do I do this?

Comment: Then you could use `.hasChild()` to see if that user has it listed: `".read": "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('accesTo').hasChild($someName)`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It works! And could you please edit your answer as well? Because I edited the question...